# Android Studio adb on Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to connect the device from USB to Wifi but the command prompt tells me all the time that adb is not found.

But it is definitly inside my folder: "~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools"
it contain:

```
adb          e2fsdroid  hprof-conv  mke2fs       package.xml        sqlite3
api          etc1tool   lib64       mke2fs.conf  sload_f2fs         systrace
dmtracedump  fastboot   make_f2fs   NOTICE.txt   source.properties
```

I start with

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

Here I get the error message. What I do wrong here?

Comment: Add `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools` into `$PATH`.

Comment: Thank you, it works

Answer (score 11):

Your shell doesn't know where to look when you call `adb` that's why you need to specify it.

First check which shell you're using by calling `echo $SHELL` - the usual ones on Linux are bash and zsh. For Bash the config file is in `~/.bash_profile`, for zsh it's in `~/.zshrc`.

Depending on what shell you're using open that file and add this line into it:

```sh
export PATH=${PATH}:$HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/
```

And restart the shell.

Then you can check that you the `adb` location is recognized with:

```
adb --version
```